# How to set default fields in custom list view template

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, display-template

I have created a custom list view using a java script file and uploaded the file in the Display templates folder in master pages.

Now when i use the template to create a view in a list, i want some set of fields to be selected by default. how do i do that. Do i need to add some property in my .js file?
Below is the code of .js file

```
var mjhViews = mjhViews || {};

mjhViews.itemHtml = function (ctx) {
  var returnHtml='<div>';
  returnHtml+='<a href="'+ctx.CurrentItem.URL+'">'+'<img src="'+ctx.CurrentItem.Image+'" alt="This is '+ctx.CurrentItem.Title+'" width="42" height="42" border="0">'+'</a>';
  returnHtml+='</div>';
  return returnHtml;
};

(function () {
  var mjhOverrides = {};
  mjhOverrides.Templates = {};

  mjhOverrides.Templates.Header = "<div id='MyCustomView' style='width: 100%; max-width: 600px;'><section class='regular slider'>";
  mjhOverrides.Templates.Item = mjhViews.itemHtml;
  mjhOverrides.Templates.Footer = "</section></div>";

  mjhOverrides.ListTemplateType = 100;
  mjhOverrides.BaseViewID = 1;

    // The postRenderHandler attends the OnPostRender event
    mjhOverrides.OnPostRender = function (ctx) {
        // You can manipulate the DOM in the postRender event


    loadCSS("https://kcsorg.sharepoint.com/sites/Democarousel/SiteAssets/slick/slick.css");
    loadCSS("https://kcsorg.sharepoint.com/sites/Democarousel/SiteAssets/slick/slick-theme.css");
    loadCSS("https://kcsorg.sharepoint.com/sites/Democarousel/SiteAssets/CustomCss.css");
    var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;

    alert(siteUrl + "/_catalogs/masterpage/Display%20Templates/Libs/jquery-2.2.0.min.js");

    loadScript(siteUrl + "/_catalogs/masterpage/Display%20Templates/Libs/jquery-2.2.0.min.js", function() {
        loadScript(siteUrl + "/_catalogs/masterpage/Display%20Templates/Libs/slick.js", function() {
            loadScript(siteUrl + "/SiteAssets/CustomScript.js", function(){
            });
          });
        });

    }  

  SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(mjhOverrides);

  function loadCSS(url) {
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var style = document.createElement('link');
        style.type = 'text/css';
        style.rel = 'stylesheet';
        style.href = url;
        head.appendChild(style);
    }
    function loadScript(url, callback) {
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = url;
        script.onreadystatechange = callback;
        script.onload = callback;
        head.appendChild(script);
    }

})();
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you're writing, and explain a little bit the steps you've taken?

Comment: below is the code of the js file

Comment: Also, what do you by: I want some set of fields to be selected by default, how selected?

Comment: when i use this custom view template to create a view, i want some of the fields to be selected by default when i click on my custom view template.